# How to bind a array form field with Playframework scala

Tags: forms, scala, binding, playframework, playframework-2.0

The form I have to handle has something like this:

```html
<label for="features_1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="features_1" name="features[]" value="4"> foo
</label>
<label for="features_2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="features_2" name="features[]" value="8"> bar
</label>
```

I can get the array like this

```scala
request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("features[]")
```

which gives me when both items are selected `List(4, 8)`

But when I try to bind this in a form

```scala
case class MyFeatures(features: Seq[Long])

val myForm = Form (
    mapping(
      "features" -> seq(longNumber)
    )(MyFeatures.apply)(MyFeatures.unapply)
)
```

<del>I always get an empty sequence, same with "features[]"</del>

**EDIT**

The above example actually works, the issue was somewhere else. Upon binding play translates the features to feature[0]=4 and features[1]=8 which is then handled correctly in the seq(...) or list(...) mappings

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the surrounding code, like how you bind the form from the request. Also, are there no apply/unapply functions on myForm?

Comment: Ok, something is fishy, according to the form bind code name[] values should be expanded to name[0], name[1]... I'll have to debug this a bit more. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala#L90

Comment: Ok, my problem was totally somewhere else, using the wrong field name in my form, the provided example actually works correcly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
<label for="features_1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="features_1" name="features[0]" value="4"> foo
</label>
<label for="features_2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="features_2" name="features[1]" value="8"> bar
</label>
```

**EDIT**

Or:

```
myForm.bind(myForm.bindFromRequest.data + ("features"-> request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("features[]"))).fold(
...
)
```

This will bind all other fields from request directly, and then when it comes to features, they are going to be added manually.
If you don't need to bind more data then just write:

```
myForm.bind("features"-> request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("features[]")).fold(
...
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal but I have no control over the form creation and since play seems to have this inputCheckboxGroup I suppose there must be some way to fix this on the backend side

Comment: Try to bind your form using the the suggestion I added in my edit.